# Change same HTML tag twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following h3:

```
<h3 class="loginheading" id="loginStatus">Replace Me</h3>
```

And a java-script function:

```
$("#loginStatus").replaceWith("<img src='x.jpg'> xD");
$("#loginStatus").replaceWith("<img src='y.jpg'> xX");
```

After this functions the value of the heading is: `xD`

Why is this not xX? How can I get the xX at the end?

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/nR4p5/1/)

Comment: After your first replace, #loginStatus does not exist anymore.. What exactly are you trying to do with the two replaceWith operations there?

Comment: use jquery toggle() function and pass image value in it

Answer (score 3):

It's because `replaceWith()` function replaces whole `h3#loginStatus` tag including itself. So after first JS line, this `h3` element doesn't exists anymore.

You should use `html()` here to set inner html content..

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginStatus").html("<img src=''> xD");
    $("#loginStatus").html("<img src=''> xX");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rc5Nn/

Answer (score 2):

After your first `replaceWith`, your `h3#loginStatus` doesn't exists anymore. Then it cannot be replaced a second time.

You can use `html()` instead, if your goal is to keep your `h3`, and change the content :

```
$("#loginStatus").html("<img src='x.jpg'> xD");
$("#loginStatus").html("<img src='y.jpg'> xX");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the loginStatus ID so you can no longer reference it after your first replace hence why it stays the same.

You can use .html instead to replace only the inner contents of the loginStatus header.

```
$("#loginStatus").html("<img src='x.jpg'> xD");
$("#loginStatus").html("<img src='y.jpg'> xX");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#loginStatus").replaceWith("<img src='x.jpg'> xD");
```

after this the elemnt $("#loginStatus") is replaced with " xD" so there is no elemnt   $("#loginStatus") for this function to replace

```
$("#loginStatus").replaceWith("<img src='y.jpg'> xX");
```

you can use .html instead of replaceWIth

Answer (score 0):

```
.replaceWith( newContent )
```

**Description: Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed. #JQuery**

So the h3 was replaced with the first java-script statement, so `$("#loginStatus").html("<img src='y.jpg'> xX");` will not work since no element with id= "loginStatus" doesn't exist